# Where is the declaration of JUnit Matcher#startsWith?

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

I was browsing the [junit `ExpectedExceptions`' javadoc](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html) and I can't understand where the `startsWith` in their example comes from (marked HERE in the code). I checked the [`CoreMatcher` utility class](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/hamcrest/CoreMatchers.html) but could not find any static `startsWith` method.

Where is that method located?

(I can obviously write it myself but that's not the point)

```
public static class HasExpectedException {
    @Rule
    public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void throwsNullPointerExceptionWithMessage() {
        thrown.expect(NullPointerException.class);
        thrown.expectMessage("happened?");
        thrown.expectMessage(startsWith("What")); //HERE
        throw new NullPointerException("What happened?");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most likely this is the `startsWith` method from the Hamcrest [`org.hamcrest.Matchers` class](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 10):

```
import static org.hamcrest.core.StringStartsWith.startsWith;
```

enables both

```
assertThat(msg, startsWith ("what"));
```

and

```
ExpectedException.none().expectMessage(startsWith("What")); //HERE
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [ExpectedException](https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.java), we can see that there are two expectMessage methods defined, one String and one Matcher, which is indeed `org.hamcrest.Matcher`.

```
/**
 * Adds to the list of requirements for any thrown exception that it should
 * <em>contain</em> string {@code substring}
 */
public void expectMessage(String substring) {
    expectMessage(containsString(substring));
}

/**
 * Adds {@code matcher} to the list of requirements for the message returned
 * from any thrown exception.
 */
public void expectMessage(Matcher<String> matcher) {
    expect(hasMessage(matcher));
}
```